# Perl: Debug for uninitialized s///?

Tags: perl, debugging

I'm some trouble finding the problem with my program. Getting the error:

`Use of uninitialized value in substitution (s///)`

I realize this has been asked before, but that didn't help me. I realize `$1` might be unitialized, but I was wondering if you guys could help me figure out why?

Here's the problem part of the code:

```
$one_match_ref->{'sentence'} = $1 if ($line =~ /^Parsing \[sent. \d+ len. \d+\]: \[(.+)\]/);
$one_match_ref->{'sentence'} =~ s/, / /g;
```

EDIT: I have declared the `$one_match_ref->{'sentence'}` like so:

```
my $sentence;
$one_match_ref = {
        chapternumber => $chapternumber_value,
        sentencenumber => $sentencenumber_value,
        sentence => $sentence, ##Get from parsed text: remove commas
        grammar_relation => $grammar_relation_value, ##Get from parsed text: split?
        arg1 => $argument1, ##Get from parsed text: first_dependencyword
        arg2 => $argument2 ##Get from parsed text: second_dependencyword
    };
```

But none of these variables have anything assigned to them.

My attempts:

**A.** If I put: `if( defined (one_match_ref->{'sentence'}))` after the s///, it works. But this is cumbersome, and seems to be avoiding the problem instead of fixing it.

The last time I used that fix, it was because my loop had an "off-by-one" error, I don't think this is the case this time.

**B.** If I declare: `my $sentence = '';` It prints, but with **a lot of blank lines** in between. How can I eliminate these?

EDIT: For interest and efficiency purposes: Is it better to use split to get what I want?

Thanks in advance for any help or advice. Let me know if you need an example of the file format.

Comment: Perl is all about the details. That something "prints blank lines" does not really give any information. We need to see code, input and desired output. Errors **with** line numbers is also nice.

There is no way anyone can say whether split would work better, without seeing the input, or knowing what you are using now.

Unless we see your print statement, there is no way we can say why it is printing a lot of blank lines.

Comment: I tried implementing the answer from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298895/perl-beginner-which-data-structure-should-i-use

Thanks for letting me know, I've added an edited portion to include what you asked (from the resources I have at the moment)

Comment: Never seen a data-extract type question get closed for being "too narrow" before. No two such questions are exactly the same. I'll take a look at this when I get back home, see if I can add something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code boils down to

```
my $sentence;
$one_match_ref = { sentence => $sentence };
() if ($line =~ /^Parsing \[sent. \d+ len. \d+\]: \[(.+)\]/);
$one_match_ref->{'sentence'} =~ s/, / /g;
```

You assign `undef` to `$one_match_ref->{'sentence'}`, then you try to remove the commas from it. That doesn't make any sense, thus the warning.

Maybe you want

```
my $sentence;
$one_match_ref = { sentence => $sentence };
if ($line =~ /^Parsing \[sent. \d+ len. \d+\]: \[(.+)\]/) {
   $one_match_ref->{'sentence'} = $1;
   $one_match_ref->{'sentence'} =~ s/, / /g;
}
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a bunch. Broke it down perfectly. I thought I had tried that though...

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure it's `$1` that's uninitialised here but rather `$one_match_ref->{'sentence'}`.

That value is set if and only if the line matches the regex. Otherwise it's not touched at all.

My reasoning is that it's complaining during the *substitute* rather than the assignment. You could *possibly* fix it by simply setting `$one_match_ref->{'sentence'}` to a known value before those two lines (such as the empty string).

But this depends on what you're actually using those values for.

Comment: I believe I did set it to the known value of "", but as stated, it then printed many of empty lines. Thanks for helping further identifying the problem!